# Подарки в ВК через Developers

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Существует такая фича в ВК, которая позволяет бесплатно отправить подарок "Сеня" самому себе через VK Developers (в этом видео всё подробно описывается: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fnxikCaGHA). Я бы хотел поэкспериментировать с id подарка в команде, чтобы подарить другой, но я уже когда-то использовал этот "баг", и этого не получается, и высвечивается код:

```
{
"error": {
"error_code": 17,
"error_msg": "Validation required: please open redirect_uri in browser",
"request_params": [{
"key": "gift_id",
"value": "813"
}, {
"key": "guid",
"value": "48535"
}],
"redirect_uri": "https://m.vk.com/...=здесьбылицифрыслатинскимибуквами"
}
}
```

Мне хотелось бы узнать, почему так происходит вместо того, как было в первый раз и показано в видео, и можно ли эту штуку обойти, чтобы дальше получать подарки?

Comment: Какое конкретно слово вам непонятно в фразе «please open redirect_uri in browser»?

Comment: Andreymal, мне в принципе здесь не понятен контекст этой фразы.